# Currencyisocode field in managed package for non multicurrency field orgs?

Tags: apex

I want to use currencyisocode field in managedpackage to store currency type information bur for some orgs multicurrency was not enabled so If I use currencyisocode field I'm getting error. I want to use something like this

```
If(mcEnabled)
   demo.Currencyisocode=USD;
else
   demo.democurrency__c=USD;
insert demo;
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve above scenario.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use CurrencyISOCode in any of your code, you are essentially creating a dependency on the target org having MC enabled. To ensure that you don't create this dependency, you'd need to use dynamic DML, for example:

```
if(mcEnabled)
    demo.put('CurrencyISOCode', 'USD');
else
    demo.put('DemoCurrency__c', 'USD');
insert demo;
```

However, you would also have to leave DemoCurrency__c unmanaged in this scenario (otherwise, in orgs where MC was enabled, you'd have a redundant field) and add as a post installation step. Note, you would also have to retrieve those fields dynamically in SOQL too to avoid the dependency being created.

Comment: thanks for reply.demo is the object .I want to insert this record .Mentioned mapping is not working for me

Comment: can you be more specific about why it is not working for you?